# Unmerge of the accounts with different mail id

Tags: support, user-accounts

I had account A with stack overflow with email id An and an account B with email id B. The account A was older by 5 months compared to account B.

A month back they got automatically merged when I chose to merge while in an attempt to log in. Can I dis-merge them now and only have my account B of stack overflow with email id B for my?  I ask this because I no longer own the email id A.

Comment: But why did you create two accounts?

Comment: Why would you want to un-merge them? Can't you just remove the unwanted email ID from your account?

Comment: becasue I could not sign into my old SO account somehow...

Comment: @Bart...is it possible to unmerge?

Comment: If you go to your network profile and then click on "my logins" you should get a list of the IDs attached to your account. You should be able to remove the unwanted one I think.

Comment: @Bart...ya I did that and removed the email id A..but my SO profile shows "member since 10 months"...doesn't the mail id removal show the actual time of membership? which in my case is 5 months..at the time of merge the time of membership increased by 5 months because it took the old account which was created 5 months back...now it should show 10 - 5 = 5 months...

Comment: "Something something, plausible explanation, something"....who cares. ;)

Comment: @rotating_image why are you so worried that your account is still related to Login A?

Comment: @rotating_image - you have been a member for 10 months. The two accounts were both you and the second merged into the first.

Comment: @rotating_image but to address your membership question, you have been a member for 10 months, that hasn't changed, you just changed your login provider.  SO's user account is deeper than just a login, it will persist unless you delete your account regardless of how many times you change your logins.

Answer (score 4):

Once two accounts are merged, it is rather difficult to unmerge them (if not impossible). It is not automatically done when you remove one of the email IDs associated with the user account, though; it would not make sense for this to happen.

In your case, as you are able to log in into your account, it is not necessary to unmerge the accounts.